# Scripting with default windows tools (windows server 2008)

Tags: vbscript

I am using VbScript to automate some tasks at work. I got stuck trying to code following actions:

- move mouse to the specific point on the screen and click <--- No proper metod found
- print screen an application <--- Sendkeys method doesn't allow such action

Let's assume I only have tools default for windows server 2008. As the company's procedure to install anything external on computers is pretty complicated, I'd rather avoid it.

My questions are following:

- am I able to code it without downloading from external sources? (got only default tools for windows server 2008)

  - if no, then what would You reccomend me to download?
- should I stick to VBscript or better switch to coding in a different language?
- I read in some sources, that I can use .Net objects to code it in VBscript, but I don't know how or does it solve my problem at all. Please, can someone briefly explain it to me?

Thank's for all Your answers. ;)

Comment: google is your friend, go to it and typ ein VBA Print Screen, and then vba Move Mouse.  You will get a faster answer this way.....

Comment: I did it and was searching for long. Do u mean I could use VBA instead of VBscript and acheive both things?

Comment: `VBScript` lacks of features essential to achieve your tasks: to move and point mouse omitted `Declare` (for declaring libraries, esp. `user32.dll` for this purpose); omitted all the `Clipboard Collection`  to manipulate with `PrtScr` outcome; I'd switch to `VB.NET` or a variant of `C`-language